# Timer and a repeater Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Hello everyone i have a timer with with display each item duration of a product, the problem is when the duration finished, i want it to rebind the item but  it give this error

**Collection was modified; enumeration operation may not execute.**

```
  Private Sub UpdateDuration()
    For Each item As RepeaterItem In repItems.Items

        Dim hidden = TryCast(item.FindControl("HiddenField1"), HiddenField)

        Dim label2 = TryCast(item.FindControl("lblTimer"), Label)
        'Grab your DateTime object (checking that it exists)'

        'Store your TimeSpan Difference'
        Dim ts = (DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse(hidden.Value))
        Dim travelTime As New TimeSpan(0, 0, 0, 0)
        Dim result2 As Integer = TimeSpan.Compare(ts, travelTime)
        If result2 <= 0 Then

            'Now you can output your time as you please (excluding any decimal points)'
            label2.Text = String.Format("Time Left: {0:dd\:hh\:mm\:ss}", ts)
            label2.Text = String.Format("{0:dd\:hh\:mm\:ss}", ts)
            label2.Text = Replace(label2.Text, ":", " Days ", , 1)
            label2.Text = Replace(label2.Text, ":", " Hours ", , 1)
            label2.Text = Replace(label2.Text, ":", " Mins ", , 1)
            label2.Text = Replace(label2.Text, ":", " Sec ", , 1)

        Else

            timer1.Enabled = True
            BindItems()

        End If
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

try this for loop instead of foreach rest code as it is

```
For index = 0 To repItems.Items.Count - 1
    Dim item As RepeaterItem = repItems.Items(index)
Next
```

Comment: sorry how can i use this for a datalist please

Comment: For index = 0 To DataList1.Items - 1
            Dim item As DataListItem = DataList1.Items(index)
        Next

Comment: try this but it is telling that Error 2 Operator '-' is not defined for types '' i move to data list so that i can add paging easily

Comment: try what?? i don't understand

Comment: try updated code.update snipppet for " Error 2 Operator '-' is not defined for types"